# jQuery-Validate / css - multiple 'classes'?

Tags: css, jquery-validate

I'm using a class for input fields to control their style. Now I want to use the jQuery validate plugin which needs the class to be 'required'. Is it possible to chain multiple classes? Here's what isn't working:

```
<input type=text id=Example class="requred textInput">
```

Comment: use quotes for `id` and `type` also.

Comment: missing an `i` in the `required` class name..

Comment: just tested it and it does work if you correct the spelling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sure this is possible, but you have a spelling in **required**, and may be that's why it does not work.

```
<input type="text" id="Example" class="required textInput">
```

Comment: Doh! too early in the morning for me. Thanks DanielB